# how to set location in my project structure?

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

When I setup  Android Studio I have an error because my user name is have space 
can not set path SDK & NDK 
- I change SDK path to `C:\Andriod\sdk` 
and when install any Gradle Version find it in  `C:\Users\Omar Ibrahim\.gradle`
- in my  environment variables  I add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT & ANDROID_AVD_HOME & JAVA_HOME` only 
what can I do to solve this message below ?

> NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

I'm using Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, etc.) but the problem is not solved.

Comment: "NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN" this isn't an error, or even a warning.

Comment: My project have error cannot resolve symbol `parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout" ` and  `parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab"` ,  I think this error has to do with this message

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with that message.

Answer (score 0):

See https://tekeye.uk/android/how-to-move-gradle-folder. You can use a different path (even different disk) for your **`.gradle`** directory, by changing *Service directory path* in Settings/Gradle .